# How to fix BulkIndexError when inserting large file of over 500mb into Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to insert data of size 589MB CSV format into elasticsearch, but am getting BulkIndexError how can I fix this.

Here is the sample code I try to make use of to insert the data into elasticsearch...

```
# Read the sample datasets
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\HOPE\Desktop\Data Science\Machine Learning\NLP\Covid NLP\Covid QA Project\FINAL_CORD_DATA.csv')
df.head()

from haystack.document_store.elasticsearch import ElasticsearchDocumentStore
document_store = ElasticsearchDocumentStore(host="localhost", username="", password="", index="document")

# Convert files to dicts
dicts = df.to_dict('records')

final_dicts = []
for each in dicts:
    tmp = {}
    tmp['text'] = each.pop('body_text')
    tmp['meta'] = each
    final_dicts.append(tmp)

document_store.write_documents(final_dicts)
```

here is the error I get after running the last code

```
BulkIndexError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-ca13005a46cd> in <module>
      6     final_dicts.append(tmp)
      7 
----> 8 document_store.write_documents(final_dicts)

~\Anaconda3\envs\ml\lib\site-packages\haystack\document_store\elasticsearch.py in write_documents(self, documents, index, batch_size)
    302             # Pass batch_size number of documents to bulk
    303             if len(documents_to_index) % batch_size == 0:
--> 304                 bulk(self.client, documents_to_index, request_timeout=300, refresh=self.refresh_type)
    305                 documents_to_index = []
    306 

~\Anaconda3\envs\ml\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\helpers\actions.py in bulk(client, actions, stats_only, *args, **kwargs)
    388     # make streaming_bulk yield successful results so we can count them
    389     kwargs["yield_ok"] = True
--> 390     for ok, item in streaming_bulk(client, actions, *args, **kwargs):
    391         # go through request-response pairs and detect failures
    392         if not ok:

~\Anaconda3\envs\ml\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\helpers\actions.py in streaming_bulk(client, actions, chunk_size, max_chunk_bytes, raise_on_error, expand_action_callback, raise_on_exception, max_retries, initial_backoff, max_backoff, yield_ok, *args, **kwargs)
    309 
    310             try:
--> 311                 for data, (ok, info) in zip(
    312                     bulk_data,
    313                     _process_bulk_chunk(

~\Anaconda3\envs\ml\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\helpers\actions.py in _process_bulk_chunk(client, bulk_actions, bulk_data, raise_on_exception, raise_on_error, *args, **kwargs)
    245             resp=resp, bulk_data=bulk_data, raise_on_error=raise_on_error
    246         )
--> 247     for item in gen:
    248         yield item
    249 

~\Anaconda3\envs\ml\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\helpers\actions.py in _process_bulk_chunk_success(resp, bulk_data, raise_on_error)
    186 
    187     if errors:
--> 188         raise BulkIndexError("%i document(s) failed to index." % len(errors), errors)
    189 
    190
```

Comment: I had similar issues with elasticsearch when indexing big amounts of data. Depends on what the hardware is and the index replica layout is. For the short-term workaround I suggest you split the bulk index into smaller pieces (10 docs then another 10 etc...)

Comment: How can I go about this? I have no idea

Comment: A foreach loop that bulkindexes an array that only has 10 documents.  You pop the data from  final_dicts. My python isn't up to date so I cant give you the code